# Insert Into on DUPLICATE KEY Update error

Tags: php, mysql

I used php form wizard to update a mysql database on form usubmision. PHP Form wizard only does INSERT INTO however so i searched the internet and found the on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command. I am unable to get the right syntax however for my query. Please Note the INSERT INTO works perfectly.
Just trying to work on the update part. any help will be appreciated. The query is below

```
@$pfw_strQuery = "INSERT INTO  `client`(`client_id`,`email`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`first_time`,`password`)VALUES (\"$client_id\",\"$email\",\"$first_name\",\"$last_name\",\"$first_time\",\"$textfield\") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `email` = VALUES(\"$email\"),`first_name` = VALUES(\"$first_name\"),`last_name` = VALUES(\"$last_name\"),`first_time` = VALUES (\"$first_time\"),`password` = VALUES (\"$textfield\") ";
```

Comment: Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This example is **extremely** worrying.

Answer (score 1):

Review the [MySQL documentation on `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Remove the `VALUES()` enclosures in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause if you are going to use the PHP variables in that clause.

```
$pfw_strQuery = "INSERT INTO  `client` (`client_id`,`email`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`first_time`,`password`)
  VALUES ('$client_id','$email','$first_name','$last_name','$first_time','$textfield')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `email` = '$email',
    `first_name` = '$first_name',
    `last_name` = '$last_name',
    `first_time` = '$first_time',
    `password` = '$textfield' ";
```

If you do use the `VALUES()` enclosures, it is the *column names*, not the input *variables* that belong inside.

> You can use the VALUES(col_name) function in the UPDATE clause to refer to column values from the INSERT portion of the INSERT ... UPDATE statement

```
$pfw_strQuery = "INSERT INTO  `client` (`client_id`,`email`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`first_time`,`password`)
  VALUES ('$client_id','$email','$first_name','$last_name','$first_time','$textfield')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `email` = VALUES(`email`),
    `first_name` = VALUES(`first_name`),
    `last_name` = VALUES(`last_name`),
    `first_time` = VALUES(`first_time`),
    `password` = VALUES(`textfield`) ";
```

Note that I have replaced all your escaped double quotes with single quotes.  While MySQL supports double quotes for string literals, single quotes are more standard and portable across other RDBMS.

We assume all these variables have already been correctly escaped against SQL injection. Finally, as you are probably aware, the old `mysql_*()` functions are planned for deprecation.  It is recommended to switch to a newer API like MySQLi or PDO which support prepared statements and parameterized queries, avoiding the escaping and quoting problems entirely.

Comment: @LeoStein We assume that is `client_id` in this table.